# $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh'); not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to use bootstrap-select and laravel 7 to improve the style of one my projects but when the options of the select are built dynamically the plugin does not work and I do not find the error. I have included the `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');` as proposed by this answer but still I am not able to achieve what I want. The HTML is the following and works perfectly:

blade

```
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
    <label for="state_id">State</label>
    <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="state_id" name="state_id">
        @foreach($states as $state)
            <option value="{{ $state->id }}">{{ $state->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
    <label for="city_id">City</label>
    <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="city_id" name="city_id">

    </select>
</div>
```

script

```
<script>
    $(document).on('change', '#state_id', function() {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
        let state_id = $(this).val();
        let select = $('#city_id');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '{{ route('findIDState') }}',
            data: {'id':state_id},
            success: function(data){
                select.html('');
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    select.append('<option value="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].name+'</option>');
                }
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log('this is a error');
            },
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refresh select2 after appending

```
<script>
    $(document).on('change', '#state_id', function() {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
        let state_id = $(this).val();
        let select = $('#city_id');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '{{ route('findIDState') }}',
            data: {'id':state_id},
            success: function(data){
                select.html('');
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    select.append('<option value="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].name+'</option>');
                }
               $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log('this is a error');
            },
        });
    }).trigger('change');
</script>
```